# In Flows on screen can I create Picklist of Accounts which having Opportunity?

Tags: visual-workflow

I created Flow, on Screen widget I want picklist of Accounts which have opportunities,
but I don't find any way to do that.

when I create record choice set on the opportunity, then I can't find Account Name on the choice label as shown in the image, so I gave AccountId,

if I give this record choice set to picklist choice on screen, it only shows record ids of account in picklist after running it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can't show the names of Accounts as record choice labels since it's not a direct field on Opportunity.

One alternative would be to create a formula field on Opportunity which stores the names of Accounts (`Account.Name`) and use this field as a choice label in Record Choice Set.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this using a brand new extension called [Get Lookup Collection.](https://unofficialsf.com/automate-junction-updates-with-getchildcollection-and-getlookupcollection/) Basically, you'll be looking up Accounts from Opportunity using the AccountId field on Opportunity, and this will return a list of Accounts. You may get some duplicates if you do that. If that's a problem, leave a comment on the Get Lookup Collection page. You could also try adding the [Dedupe action discussed here.](https://unofficialsf.com/de-dupe-an-sobject-collection-and-schedule-an-email-in-flow/)